# startupService.load() from ng-alain is blocked by @delon/auth

Tags: angular, ng-alain

I am using ng-alain for my project

I am trying to move the starup logic to backend which check the presence of token and responds the startup data accordingly. But the request is intercept by the @delon/auth due to absence of token.

[image]